# SCIP cannot read my input

Tags: scip

I'm trying to use the SCIP solver (http://scip.zib.de/). My input (`1.lp`) is in `lpsolve` format. It looks like this:

```
max:  +2 x_0_0;
 +x_0_0 <= 1;
 +x_0_0 <= 1;
 -3x_0_0 <= 0;
0 <= x_0_0 <= 1;
int x_0_0;
```

I run SCIP like this:

```
"c:\Program Files\SCIP\scip.exe" -f 1.lp -l 1.lp.out
```

However, SCIP generates this output:

```
SCIP version 3.0.0 [precision: 8 byte] [memory: block] [mode: optimized] [LP solver: SoPlex 1.7.0] [GitHash: c95600b]
Copyright (c) 2002-2012 Konrad-Zuse-Zentrum fuer Informationstechnik Berlin (ZIB)

External codes: 
  SoPlex 1.7.0         Linear Programming Solver developed at Zuse Institute Berlin (soplex.zib.de) [GitHash: 657dfe5]
  cppad-20120101.3     Algorithmic Differentiation of C++ algorithms developed by B. Bell (www.coin-or.org/CppAD)
  Ipopt 3.10.2         Interior Point Optimizer developed by A. Waechter et.al. (www.coin-or.org/Ipopt)

user parameter file <scip.set> not found - using default parameters

read problem <[...]1.lp>
============

  input: 
         ^
error reading file <[...]1.lp>
```

I guess that means it is choking on a whitespace... What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

See my answer for details. After giving the input in CPLEX format, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that SCIP apparently cannot read lpsolve input files. The LP format they are referring to in this [overview of readable file formats](http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/group__FILEREADERS.php) is in fact the CPLEX LP format.